# Create React App - Build keeps failing on Netlify but works locally

Tags: create-react-app, netlify

```
10:52:56 PM: There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
10:52:56 PM: It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
10:52:56 PM: The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
10:52:56 PM:   "babel-jest": "23.6.0"
10:52:56 PM: Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
10:52:56 PM: However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:
10:52:56 PM:   /opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 24.7.1)
10:52:56 PM: Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
10:52:56 PM: If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
10:52:56 PM: That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
10:52:56 PM: To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
10:52:56 PM:   1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
10:52:56 PM:   2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
10:52:56 PM:   3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
10:52:56 PM:   4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
10:52:56 PM: In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
10:52:56 PM: If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
10:52:56 PM:   5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
10:52:56 PM:      This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
10:52:56 PM:   6. Check if /opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
10:52:56 PM:      For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
10:52:56 PM:   7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
10:52:56 PM:      This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.
10:52:56 PM: If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
10:52:56 PM: That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
10:52:56 PM: P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
```

So I recently pushed a new build to my app and got the above error, something to do with babel-jest. This is not in my package.json, it must be a peer dependency or something.

The build works great locally, I have confirmed by deleting the node_modules and the package-lock.json and it all installs and runs just fine.

When I push to master, netlify logs this error and just won't move on.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the debugging article in netlify's community:  https://community.netlify.com/t/common-issue-debugging-site-builds/142 .  You could also try a build without cache from the "trigger deploy" button on the deploy listing page, and selecting the "clear build cache" option since that might help out with peer dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it turned out to be related to babel-jest version, strange problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what fixed it for me was to search in the `package-lock.json` for `babel-jest`. I then added that version to a resolutions entry in my `package.json` as follows:

`"resolutions": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0"
  }`

This solved the problem and my app published correctly on Netlify.

Comment: But what happens when the babel-jest version changes?

Comment: for the moment, you'll need to change that also, unless you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is kind of old and the answer has already been chosen but the above answer doesn't work for me.So here how i solve my problem

put package-lock.json in .gitignore file but if you already uploaded it to github without mentioning it to .gitignore file then remove it from git cache(local repo)

```
git rm -r --cached package-lock.json
git add .
git commit -m 'Remove package-lock.json'
git push origin master
```

In you netlify site goto Site settings->Build & Deploy->Environment and put the following inside the environement variable

`SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`

and put the follow to Build setting->Build Command if your netlify build assume warning as error

`CI=false npm run build`

Comment: Thanks setting up `CI=false npm run build ` worked I got fed up by the build failing